# Approve Smart Contract to transfer tokens using transferFrom

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to use **approve** and **transferFrom** to send tokens through a smart Contract using **Remix** but getting **ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance** error. I have deployed 3 smart contracts(**Token**, **TransferToken**, **Owner**) using same Public Address. I know there are some similar questions and I did my research and tried to solve this issue but no success Kindly have a look.

**Token.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';

contract Token is ERC20 {

   constructor() ERC20('My Token', 'TTT') {
       _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** 18);
   }

}
```

**TransferToken.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

import 'https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
import 'Token.sol';
import 'Owner.sol';

contract TransferToken {

   function transfer() external {
       Token token = Token(Token.sol Contract Address);
       token.transfer(msg.sender, 100);
   }

   function transferFrom(address recipient, uint256 amount) external {
       Token token = Token(Token.sol Contract Address);
       token.transferFrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount );

   }

}
```

**Owner.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.5;

import 'Token.sol';
import 'TransferToken.sol';

contract Owner {
   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external {
       Token token = Token(Token.sol Contract Address);
       token.approve(TransferToken.sol Contract Address, amount);

       TransferToken transferToken =TransferToken(TransferToken.sol Contract Address);
       transferToken.transferFrom(recipient, amount);

   }

}
```

Comment: Please add the call you are doing to get the error, you have 2 `transferForm` functions we dont know which one you are reporting

Comment: so after deploying all 3 if I execute **transFrom** in **TransferToken.sol** i get **ERC:transfer amount exceeds allowance** and if i run **transferFrom** in **Owner.sol** I get **ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance**

Comment: Well you need to call the `approve` function with the amount to be transfered before any transfers occur

Comment: @ZSA I tried your code in Remix and it works as expected when Owner contract has enough tokens in their balance.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to send it directly from owner address instead of sending token to owner account first.                                                                                                             I opted for another approach and used approve function inside **token** contract to approve **Transfertoken** contract address and it worked like that